# Does anyone use config files for javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, configuration

We have javascript files that are environment specific, and so I was thinking of going down the path of creating a generic way to read in an XML (config) file to store different environment specific settings.  I was curious to know if anybody else on here does that (or if not, is there a reason why you don't)?

Comment: XML bleccch!  You've got JSON available!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JSON is hundreds of times faster to consume than XML, bring a native JavaScript object itself. Attach and forget.

**EDIT:**

James Westgate's example is JSON. You can use this inline or as an external file or even loaded via AJAX.

Here is another example:

```
var clientData = {}
clientData.dataset1 = [
    {name:'Dave', age:'41', userid:2345},
    {name:'Vera', age:'32', userid:9856}
]

alert(clientData.dataset1[0].name)
```

Comment: Actually my example is not valid JSON, and neither is yours.
In my example it is not intended to be loaded via ajax- loaded directly as a script file is more efficient. If it were being retrieved from an API call via ajax then that would be a different matter.

Comment: To avoid the use of long names I would suggest using something like `var data = clientData.dataset1` within a function that possibly needs many of those variables.

Answer (score 36):

All you need to do is load a javascript file with some variable definitions, ideally namespaced. You can use a single object literal for this:

```
var config = {
  option1: 'goods', 
  option2: {name: 'option2'}, 
  option3: ['o','p','t','3']
}
```

Then load that file as your first script and you will have access to config information in each subsequent script eg

```
if (config.option1 == 'goods') doStuff();
```

Comment: prefix the variable with a function or other variable to give it more meaning/ context eg  config.option1 instead of just option1

Answer (score 13):

Why not use a separate js file to store your environment-specific settings?

Just like you can use multiple CSS files to style your page, you can use multiple js files as well.

So you could create a file called app-config.js with specific settings:

```
var SiteName = "MyWebsite.com";
var HeaderImage = "http://mycdn.com/images/mywebsite/header.png";
```

And then you include the js on your pages like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing you might consider is to have the pages themselves include little Javascript blocks to provide just this sort of configuration information. Often, you really only need a small amount of information for URL building etc.  I'll give a JSP example:

```
<script>
  var appConfig = {
    'syndicate': '${environ.syndicate}',
    'urlBase': '${environ.urlBase}'
  };
</script>
```

Then your "pure" Javascript code can look to `window.appConfig` to get critical information. Obviously this would get to be a mess if you needed a whole lot of stuff.

This is particularly easy when your pages are built via some templating system in your server-side environment. That way, you only have to set the script tag up in one place (or a small number of places; the templates in other words) and all the pages get it automatically.

(*edited to eliminate weird variable declaration*)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pull down XML files using something like jquery ([http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/)](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/).

However, I'd like to pose whether environment specific client-side javascript code is really a good idea. Seems like any environment specific (ie. qa, uat, production I assume) should be handled on the server and the client should be environment agnostic

Comment: It's currently for an environment specific AJAX call.  The URL will be different depending on the environment since our different web apps have a different URL depending on the environment.  I suppose that with this little variance, the path I'm going down could be overkill, but it was something I wanted to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using YCB. Here is an example how to use it: https://github.com/yahoo/ycb/blob/master/examples/simple/app.js